# MongoDB eats 100% CPU when idle

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am running in OpenVZ container with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

MongoDB version:

```
db version v3.0.4
git version: 0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5
```

I use clean installation like described here - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

`top` shows around 100% - 150% CPU

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
30480 mongodb   20   0  548096  66920  39884 S 150.2  1.6   4:55.38 mongod
```

This is while **nothing else is going on**. Nothing else is running in the container. No queries, no connections.

I have tried lock file in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747580/mongodb-service-at-100-cpu. It's not it.

#### Edit (Log file upon start)

```
2015-07-09T14:05:48.998+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2015-07-09T14:05:48.998+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-07-09T14:05:49.061+0200 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-07-09T14:05:49.061+0200 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-07-09T14:05:49.062+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=30480 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=euler-dev
2015-07-09T14:05:49.062+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-07-09T14:05:49.062+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6.
2015-07-09T14:05:49.063+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-07-09T14:05:49.063+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.4
2015-07-09T14:05:49.063+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5
2015-07-09T14:05:49.063+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2015-07-09T14:05:49.063+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-45-73-23 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-07-09T14:05:49.063+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-07-09T14:05:49.063+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2015-07-09T14:05:49.092+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

#### Edit2 more detailed logs

A log with journaling enabled: `pastebin.com/kKx4SJ98`

Journaling disabled: `pastebin.com/s2GT71w7`

With journaling disabled the CPU usage cuts in half (around 40% - 80%). This all when idle.

Comment: Have you check this doc? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#mongodb-and-numa-hardware

Comment: Good idea - But I can't use `numactl` in OpenVZ box and also mongo doesn't issue any warning.

Comment: I think this is the warning they refer to: "WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ which can cause issues on versions of RHEL older than RHEL6" , i would suggest to upgrade to 3.0.6 because there were some issues reported with unpredictable cpu behavior in versions 3.0.4 and below. Do you  have a replica set?

Comment: We are running VMs on Debians with RedHat server cores and according to the support these issues (the ones the warning in the log refers to) were dealt with in 2013. So it shouldn't be an issue now. - I don't have a replica set. - I will update to 3.0.6 just to see if the problems persists - Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated to 3.1.6 nightly and the issue persists. It maybe related to our setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue as described here (for MySQL): [High CPU usage from MySQL with no queries at all running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/high-cpu-usage-from-mysql-with-no-queries-at-all-running)

```
sudo date -s now
```

Caused by leap second and a bug in the kernel.