# MySQL Server 5.6 Using all or very little of my resources trouble shooting?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have an application that uses a MySQL 5.6 Server.  This server is hosted on a Windows 8 VM on a server in our office closet.  A coworker of mine sent me a picture of the `mysqlId` process consistantly oscillating betwee 2% CPU usage to 99% cpu usage.  When it was installed, I selected the option that it was a dedicated server because that VM does only host the MySQL 5.6.

The queries throughput tends to max out at around 30 queries per second and 99% of these queries are answered in less than half a second, its rare we have longer queries.

Is this normal to how a MySQL 5.6 server operates CPU wise - the oscillating low to high CPU usage?  Or is it possible to set events in MySQL I should look at?  I did a `SHOW EVENTS` and I don't see any background scheduled tasks that would cause this.  Is this normal or something I should trouble shoot and if so where else can I look to?

The only other potential answer I've found is [High CPU usage from MySQL with no queries at all running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/high-cpu-usage-from-mysql-with-no-queries-at-all-running) but the link in the answer post is now broken.  Perhaps someone knows if the leap second issue is still an outstanding one for MySQL 5.6 and that could be the cause?

Edit:
Some additional information.
`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` only shows a handful of expected connections from our application.

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
auto_increment_increment    1
auto_increment_offset   1
autocommit  ON
automatic_sp_privileges ON
back_log    70
basedir C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\
big_tables  OFF
bind_address    *
binlog_cache_size   32768
binlog_checksum CRC32
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF
binlog_format   STATEMENT
binlog_max_flush_queue_time 0
binlog_order_commits    ON
binlog_row_image    FULL
binlog_rows_query_log_events    OFF
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_general_ci
collation_server    utf8_general_ci
completion_type NO_CHAIN
concurrent_insert   AUTO
connect_timeout 10
core_file   OFF
datadir C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\
date_format %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
default_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_tmp_storage_engine  InnoDB
default_week_format 0
delay_key_write ON
delayed_insert_limit    100
delayed_insert_timeout  300
delayed_queue_size  1000
disconnect_on_expired_password  ON
div_precision_increment 4
end_markers_in_json OFF
enforce_gtid_consistency    OFF
eq_range_index_dive_limit   10
event_scheduler OFF
expire_logs_days    0
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp OFF
flush   OFF
flush_time  0
foreign_key_checks  ON
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len 84
ft_min_word_len 4
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    (built-in)
general_log OFF
general_log_file    VM-WIN8PRO.log
group_concat_max_len    1024
gtid_executed   
gtid_mode   OFF
gtid_owned  
gtid_purged 
have_compress   YES
have_crypt  NO
have_dynamic_loading    YES
have_geometry   YES
have_openssl    DISABLED
have_profiling  YES
have_query_cache    YES
have_rtree_keys YES
have_ssl    DISABLED
have_symlink    YES
host_cache_size 228
hostname    VM-WIN8PRO
ignore_builtin_innodb   OFF
ignore_db_dirs  
init_connect    
init_file   
init_slave  
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  ON
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 2097152
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_autoextend_increment 1000
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    1
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 8589934592
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering all
innodb_checksum_algorithm   crc32
innodb_checksums    ON
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  ON
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method 
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  1048576
innodb_log_file_size    2147483648
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   .\
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   300
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 300
innodb_purge_threads    1
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  4
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   0
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   ON
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  1.2.10
innodb_write_io_threads 4
interactive_timeout 28800
join_buffer_size    262144
keep_files_on_create    OFF
key_buffer_size 8388608
key_cache_age_threshold 300
key_cache_block_size    1024
key_cache_division_limit    100
large_files_support ON
large_page_size 0
large_pages OFF
lc_messages en_US
lc_messages_dir C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\
lc_time_names   en_US
license GPL
local_infile    ON
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
log_bin OFF
log_bin_basename    
log_bin_index   
log_bin_trust_function_creators OFF
log_bin_use_v1_row_events   OFF
log_error   .\VM-WIN8PRO.err
log_output  NONE
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF
log_slave_updates   OFF
log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes  0
log_warnings    1
long_query_time 10.000000
low_priority_updates    OFF
lower_case_file_system  ON
lower_case_table_names  1
master_info_repository  FILE
master_verify_checksum  OFF
max_allowed_packet  4194304
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size 1073741824
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors  100
max_connections 100
max_delayed_threads 20
max_error_count 64
max_heap_table_size 16777216
max_insert_delayed_threads  20
max_join_size   18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data    1024
max_prepared_stmt_count 16382
max_relay_log_size  0
max_seeks_for_key   4294967295
max_sort_length 1024
max_sp_recursion_depth  0
max_tmp_tables  32
max_user_connections    0
max_write_lock_count    4294967295
metadata_locks_cache_size   1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances   8
min_examined_row_limit  0
multi_range_count   256
myisam_data_pointer_size    6
myisam_max_sort_file_size   107374182400
myisam_mmap_size    18446744073709551615
myisam_recover_options  OFF
myisam_repair_threads   1
myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608
myisam_stats_method nulls_unequal
myisam_use_mmap OFF
named_pipe  OFF
net_buffer_length   16384
net_read_timeout    30
net_retry_count 10
net_write_timeout   60
new OFF
old OFF
old_alter_table OFF
old_passwords   0
open_files_limit    6158
optimizer_prune_level   1
optimizer_search_depth  62
optimizer_switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosesc...
optimizer_trace enabled=off,one_line=off
optimizer_trace_features    greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
optimizer_trace_limit   1
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size    16384
optimizer_trace_offset  -1
performance_schema  ON
performance_schema_accounts_size    100
performance_schema_digests_size 10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size   10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size   10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size    10
performance_schema_hosts_size   100
performance_schema_max_cond_classes 80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances   3300
performance_schema_max_file_classes 50
performance_schema_max_file_handles 32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances   6770
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes    200
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  15600
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes   30
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances 9000
performance_schema_max_socket_classes   10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances 220
performance_schema_max_stage_classes    150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes    167
performance_schema_max_table_handles    4000
performance_schema_max_table_instances  12500
performance_schema_max_thread_classes   50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances 300
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size   512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size    100
performance_schema_setup_objects_size   100
performance_schema_users_size   100
pid_file    C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\VM-WIN8PRO.pid
plugin_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin\
port    3307
preload_buffer_size 32768
profiling   OFF
profiling_history_size  15
protocol_version    10
query_alloc_block_size  8192
query_cache_limit   1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    1048576
query_cache_type    ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
query_prealloc_size 8192
range_alloc_block_size  4096
read_buffer_size    8192
read_only   OFF
read_rnd_buffer_size    106496
relay_log   
relay_log_basename  
relay_log_index 
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info
relay_log_info_repository   FILE
relay_log_purge ON
relay_log_recovery  OFF
relay_log_space_limit   0
report_host 
report_password 
report_port 3307
report_user 
secure_auth ON
secure_file_priv    
server_id   0
server_id_bits  32
server_uuid 02015234-de1b-11e9-8b2b-000c291e4046
shared_memory   OFF
shared_memory_base_name MYSQL
skip_external_locking   ON
skip_name_resolve   OFF
skip_networking OFF
skip_show_database  OFF
slave_allow_batching    OFF
slave_checkpoint_group  512
slave_checkpoint_period 300
slave_compressed_protocol   OFF
slave_exec_mode STRICT
slave_load_tmpdir   C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
slave_max_allowed_packet    1073741824
slave_net_timeout   3600
slave_parallel_workers  0
slave_pending_jobs_size_max 16777216
slave_rows_search_algorithms    TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
slave_skip_errors   OFF
slave_sql_verify_checksum   ON
slave_transaction_retries   10
slave_type_conversions  
slow_launch_time    2
slow_query_log  OFF
slow_query_log_file VM-WIN8PRO-slow.log
socket  MySQL
sort_buffer_size    262144
sql_auto_is_null    OFF
sql_big_selects ON
sql_buffer_result   OFF
sql_log_bin ON
sql_log_off OFF
sql_mode    STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql_notes   ON
sql_quote_show_create   ON
sql_safe_updates    OFF
sql_select_limit    18446744073709551615
sql_slave_skip_counter  0
sql_warnings    OFF
ssl_ca  
ssl_capath  
ssl_cert    
ssl_cipher  
ssl_crl 
ssl_crlpath 
ssl_key 
storage_engine  InnoDB
stored_program_cache    256
sync_binlog 0
sync_frm    ON
sync_master_info    10000
sync_relay_log  10000
sync_relay_log_info 10000
system_time_zone    Eastern Daylight Time
table_definition_cache  1400
table_open_cache    2000
table_open_cache_instances  1
thread_cache_size   9
thread_concurrency  10
thread_handling one-thread-per-connection
thread_stack    262144
time_format %H:%i:%s
time_zone   SYSTEM
timed_mutexes   OFF
tmp_table_size  4194304
tmpdir  C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp
transaction_alloc_block_size    8192
transaction_prealloc_size   4096
tx_isolation    REPEATABLE-READ
tx_read_only    OFF
unique_checks   ON
updatable_views_with_limit  YES
version 5.6.10
version_comment MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine x86_64
version_compile_os  Win64
wait_timeout    28800
```

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
Aborted_clients 13
Aborted_connects    3
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
Bytes_received  326577556
Bytes_sent  2997613823
Com_admin_commands  718
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Com_alter_db    0
Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
Com_alter_event 0
Com_alter_function  0
Com_alter_procedure 0
Com_alter_server    0
Com_alter_table 0
Com_alter_tablespace    0
Com_alter_user  0
Com_analyze 0
Com_begin   0
Com_binlog  0
Com_call_procedure  1438
Com_change_db   6
Com_change_master   0
Com_check   0
Com_checksum    0
Com_commit  0
Com_create_db   0
Com_create_event    0
Com_create_function 0
Com_create_index    0
Com_create_procedure    0
Com_create_server   0
Com_create_table    0
Com_create_trigger  0
Com_create_udf  0
Com_create_user 0
Com_create_view 14
Com_dealloc_sql 0
Com_delete  168
Com_delete_multi    0
Com_do  0
Com_drop_db 0
Com_drop_event  0
Com_drop_function   0
Com_drop_index  0
Com_drop_procedure  0
Com_drop_server 0
Com_drop_table  0
Com_drop_trigger    0
Com_drop_user   0
Com_drop_view   0
Com_empty_query 0
Com_execute_sql 0
Com_flush   0
Com_get_diagnostics 0
Com_grant   0
Com_ha_close    0
Com_ha_open 0
Com_ha_read 0
Com_help    0
Com_insert  502
Com_insert_select   16
Com_install_plugin  0
Com_kill    0
Com_load    0
Com_lock_tables 0
Com_optimize    0
Com_preload_keys    0
Com_prepare_sql 0
Com_purge   0
Com_purge_before_date   0
Com_release_savepoint   0
Com_rename_table    0
Com_rename_user 0
Com_repair  0
Com_replace 0
Com_replace_select  0
Com_reset   0
Com_resignal    0
Com_revoke  0
Com_revoke_all  0
Com_rollback    0
Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
Com_savepoint   0
Com_select  1537195
Com_set_option  475
Com_signal  0
Com_show_binlog_events  0
Com_show_binlogs    0
Com_show_charsets   1
Com_show_collations 1
Com_show_create_db  0
Com_show_create_event   0
Com_show_create_func    0
Com_show_create_proc    0
Com_show_create_table   0
Com_show_create_trigger 0
Com_show_databases  4
Com_show_engine_logs    0
Com_show_engine_mutex   0
Com_show_engine_status  0
Com_show_events 1
Com_show_errors 0
Com_show_fields 810
Com_show_function_code  0
Com_show_function_status    1
Com_show_grants 0
Com_show_keys   0
Com_show_master_status  0
Com_show_open_tables    0
Com_show_plugins    0
Com_show_privileges 0
Com_show_procedure_code 0
Com_show_procedure_status   1
Com_show_processlist    7
Com_show_profile    0
Com_show_profiles   0
Com_show_relaylog_events    0
Com_show_slave_hosts    0
Com_show_slave_status   0
Com_show_status 5
Com_show_storage_engines    1
Com_show_table_status   0
Com_show_tables 2
Com_show_triggers   0
Com_show_variables  19
Com_show_warnings   0
Com_slave_start 0
Com_slave_stop  0
Com_stmt_close  22
Com_stmt_execute    22
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    22
Com_stmt_reprepare  0
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
Com_truncate    0
Com_uninstall_plugin    0
Com_unlock_tables   0
Com_update  3825
Com_update_multi    22
Com_xa_commit   0
Com_xa_end  0
Com_xa_prepare  0
Com_xa_recover  0
Com_xa_rollback 0
Com_xa_start    0
Compression OFF
Connection_errors_accept    0
Connection_errors_internal  0
Connection_errors_max_connections   0
Connection_errors_peer_address  0
Connection_errors_select    0
Connection_errors_tcpwrap   0
Connections 32
Created_tmp_disk_tables 21183
Created_tmp_files   2717
Created_tmp_tables  1267705
Delayed_errors  0
Delayed_insert_threads  0
Delayed_writes  0
Flush_commands  1
Handler_commit  1293631
Handler_delete  9
Handler_discover    0
Handler_external_lock   8446468
Handler_mrr_init    0
Handler_prepare 0
Handler_read_first  1299944
Handler_read_key    254028093
Handler_read_last   1252
Handler_read_next   304207084
Handler_read_prev   38202765
Handler_read_rnd    10872432
Handler_read_rnd_next   382836665
Handler_rollback    75
Handler_savepoint   0
Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
Handler_update  7522597
Handler_write   38688193
Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status  not started
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   7348
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   120389632
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  0
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    17050
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   516031
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   909
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  524288
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   3817
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    1150297122
Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    3419
Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   204717
Innodb_data_fsyncs  39932
Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
Innodb_data_read    123031552
Innodb_data_reads   7862
Innodb_data_writes  42214
Innodb_data_written 578401792
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  17050
Innodb_dblwr_writes 14316
Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
Innodb_log_waits    0
Innodb_log_write_requests   27886
Innodb_log_writes   6530
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    10836
Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
Innodb_os_log_written   17500672
Innodb_page_size    16384
Innodb_pages_created    94
Innodb_pages_read   7254
Innodb_pages_written    17050
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
Innodb_row_lock_time    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
Innodb_rows_deleted 9
Innodb_rows_inserted    747
Innodb_rows_read    828295450
Innodb_rows_updated 90192
Innodb_num_open_files   189
Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
Innodb_available_undo_logs  128
Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
Key_blocks_unused   6696
Key_blocks_used 1464
Key_read_requests   42898239
Key_reads   2
Key_write_requests  15784042
Key_writes  0
Last_query_cost 0.000000
Last_query_partial_plans    0
Max_used_connections    15
Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
Open_files  51
Open_streams    0
Open_table_definitions  404
Open_tables 970
Opened_files    88888
Opened_table_definitions    404
Opened_tables   977
Performance_schema_accounts_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_digest_lost  0
Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
Performance_schema_hosts_lost   0
Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost   0
Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
Performance_schema_users_lost   0
Prepared_stmt_count 0
Qcache_free_blocks  3
Qcache_free_memory  11120
Qcache_hits 36494
Qcache_inserts  1254239
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    1223854
Qcache_not_cached   282771
Qcache_queries_in_cache 773
Qcache_total_blocks 1592
Queries 1583348
Questions   1579069
Select_full_join    1237141
Select_full_range_join  103
Select_range    4774
Select_range_check  0
Select_scan 58586
Slave_heartbeat_period  
Slave_last_heartbeat    
Slave_open_temp_tables  0
Slave_received_heartbeats   
Slave_retried_transactions  
Slave_running   OFF
Slow_launch_threads 0
Slow_queries    88
Sort_merge_passes   3906
Sort_range  597
Sort_rows   10827945
Sort_scan   28394
Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
Ssl_accepts 0
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_cipher  
Ssl_cipher_list 
Ssl_client_connects 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
Ssl_default_timeout 0
Ssl_finished_accepts    0
Ssl_finished_connects   0
Ssl_server_not_after    
Ssl_server_not_before   
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_sessions_reused 0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Ssl_verify_depth    0
Ssl_verify_mode 0
Ssl_version 
Table_locks_immediate   4223256
Table_locks_waited  0
Table_open_cache_hits   4224499
Table_open_cache_misses 977
Table_open_cache_overflows  0
Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
Tc_log_page_size    0
Tc_log_page_waits   0
Threads_cached  0
Threads_connected   14
Threads_created 18
Threads_running 3
Uptime  97668
Uptime_since_flush_status   97668
```

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
13  root    192.168.1.227:49250 tab Sleep   254     
16  root    192.168.1.227:49254 tab Sleep   254     
17  root    192.168.1.227:49356 tab Sleep   126     
18  root    192.168.1.227:49357 tab Sleep   254     
19  root    192.168.1.227:49358 tab Sleep   253     
20  root    192.168.1.227:49359 tab Sleep   2       
21  root    192.168.1.227:49360 tab Sleep   9       
22  root    192.168.1.227:49361 tab Sleep   2       
25  root    192.168.1.161:49241 tab Sleep   3092        
26  root    192.168.1.161:49256 tab Sleep   3092        
28  root    localhost:49162     Sleep   309     
29  root    localhost:49163     Sleep   309     
30  root    192.168.1.152:50916 tab Query   0   init    SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
31  root    192.168.1.152:50917 tab Sleep   407
```

Comment: here is essential acopy see if oit helps https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/atlassian-application-administrators-need-know-leap-second-bug-lurking-systems, but it is normal for every program to grap all re4spurces initially to get the job done.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the list of info.  The VM has 16 gigs allocated, of which MySQL settings give it 8 to use.  The rest of this is good info to try.  Thanks for the insight.  Added the GLOBAL VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS info to my post.  I don't know what most of it means but hopefully it means something to you.

Comment: Hoping you can post the rest of the requested info, even if you think it is OK.  Thanks for the SGS and SGV.

Comment: You can get the perl script from www.mysqltuner.com to produce the report.  It is a low-impact external script, requiring only root login to your MySQL instance.

Comment: I posted what I can.  www.mysqltuner.com does not appear to be up at the moment.

Comment: I see that you are Windows hosted.  Here is URL to download executable for mysqltuner.exe for the Windows version to execute after download from MS Command Prompt, login as root to your instance for the report preparation.  https://github.com/pmachapman

Comment: Additional information request. RAM size, Any SWAP space?, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?  Do you have flexibility to Skype TALK with me?  View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.ini [mysqld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
log_output=FILE  # from NONE someday you will need Slow Query Log and General Log's
tmp_table_size=16M  # from 4M to be same size as max_heap_table_size
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF to record the 88 slow queries for corrective action
innodb_open_files=2000  # should always match table_open_cache requested
read_buffer_size=128K  # from 8K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 3,115
query_cache_type=OFF  # from ON only 2% of queries are cached
query_cache_size=0  # from 1M to conserve RAM and CPU cycles
```

Observations,
    A) threads_connected count at 14 indicates connections are not being CLOSED when done
        confirmed with SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST
    B) select_full_join RPS of 13 indicates indexes missing when JOIN tables requested
    C) select_scan RPS of 1 indicates indexes missing on SELECT requests.

For additional assistance, use our free downloadable Utility Scripts and get in touch.

Answer (score 0):

CPU spikes can be cured only by finding the slow queries and improving them.

Also, the "Query cache" is especially useless in your situation.  Note that *each* `INSERT` triggers purging *all* entries in the QC that involve that table(s).  Turn off the QC:

```
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
```

It appears that the dataset is very small -- much smaller than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  (The only impact is that you are using more RAM than you need to.  Cut the VM size in half if you are paying for it.)

If you have trouble finding the naughty queries, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog .  Use `long_query_time = 0.5`